# Green's Function for the Half Plane

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

Im trying to solve the following problem using the Green's function:

$$\begin{align*}
\bigtriangleup u(x,y) &= 0, \quad (x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2-\{(x,y):y\leq 0\}=\mathbb{R}^2_+ \\
u(x,0) &= 1
\end{align*}$$

I have that $$u(x,y)=-\frac{y}{2}\int_{\partial \mathbb{R}^2_+}\frac{\,dx_0dy_0}{(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2}$$

I have no idea how to go about doing this integral. Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: The boundary has dimension one. Why did you get a double integral. Maybe, the $\int$ is over $\mathbb{R}_{+}^{2}$: In that case, I 'guess' it'll diverge !!!.

Comment: I originally tried it as a 1D integral but couldn't get it to converge and the slution is convergent.